# Why underscore in my database name is spoiling phpMyAdmin database list

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Recently I created a database with a name `test_test` in phpMyAdmin and just after I created it, the list of database on the left hand side spoiled suddenly, Is this a bug or I should ignore `_` in database name?

**Preview**

> localhost screen

[image]

[image]

> On selecting `test_test` database

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHPMyAdmin is grouping your databases if an underscore is used. `prefix_name`. They still work like usual, they are just displayed differently in PHPMyAdmin.

If you don't like it you can [disable it](https://serverfault.com/questions/247061/is-there-any-way-to-disable-grouping-databases-in-phpmyadmin).

Comment: So that's a kind of display bug?

Answer (score 2):

> It's not a bug, it's a feature

See http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#LeftFrameDBSeparator you can change it to other pattern or disable by setting `LeftFrameDBTree` to false